# Requiring files in executables in a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am building a gem using ruby 1.9.3 and bundler 1.1.3. In my gemspec, I use the `executables` method to specify that `bin/curd" is executable:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  ...
  gem.executables   = ["curd"]
  ...
end
```

The gem source directory has a `bin` and a `lib` directory:

```
bin/
  curd
lib/
  curd.rb
```

The `bin/curd` file uses code defined in `lib/curd`, but I haven't been able to properly require it.

How can I require the `lib/curd` file so that when the gem is installed, `bin/curd` can see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to `bin/curd`:

```
require 'curd'
```

This will require `curd` gem after installation.

Comment: I thought that `bin/curd` was part of the gem, thank you, that worked.